# How can I make a list of all questions from Stack overflow that match some tag?

Tags: zapier

Is there a way to connect Zappier and Stack overflow? I'd like to have a Google Sheet table of all questions related to specific tag. Do I need to write a scraper/parser for this or can it be done directly in Zappier?

If I would need a code for that, does anyone have any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done a similar thing in the past with RSS feeds. There are basically 2 steps:

1. You might be able to use this process to set up an RSS feed of the tags you wish to follow: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3403/rss-feed-of-your-favorite-tags
2. Then you can use the Zapier RSS trigger to start your Zap.

After that, you should be good to run whatever Zapier processes you need. I hope that helps :)

Comment: What a great work flow! I've totally missed the RSS option in Stack overflow. Thank you Henry.

Comment: No problems, glad I could help.